# querying graphql with node

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js

I am trying to query a graphQL endpoint but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. How am I supposed to set up the graphQL object to pass over. If I am trying to pass

```
{
  name {
     age
  }
}
```

How should I be wrapping this to get the correct response from the server? The full code I am currently working with is below

```
var http = require('http')
var qs = require('querystring')

var options = {
    hostname: 'url',
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/query'
}

var req = http.request(options, function(res){
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        console.log('No more data in response.')
    })
})

var query = qs.stringify({data: {classes:{}}})


req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

req.write(query)
req.end()
```

Comment: Now I found a good solution - "graphql-request". Here is the link. https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-request
Hope it helps others save time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
payload = {
    "query": `{
        name {
            age
        }
    }`
}
JSON.stringify(payload)
```

The name "query" might be different in your case. Basically, you need to convert the JSON query to string. This is how I do it with the GitHub GraphQL API v4.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example using fetch.
I think you don't need apollo client unless you really need it.

```
require('isomorphic-fetch');

fetch('https://api.example.com/graphql', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ query: '{ name { age } }' }),
})
```

Comment: Note that unlike running javascript in the browser, node does not have a native fetch() function, hence the need to ```require('isomorphic-fetch');``` in this example. There are other packages you can install to get a simple fetch() in node, eg ```const fetch = require('node-fetch');``` You need to run ```npm install iosmorphic-fetch``` (or ```npm install your-chosen-fetch-package``` to gain access to the fetch() function in node.

Comment: fetch() was added as default in node v18 https://blog.logrocket.com/fetch-api-node-js/

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the easiest way to do this is by using the [Apollo Client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@apollo/client) library `@apollo/client`. You should note however that this library unfortunately makes the assumption that you're using React, and there's no vanilla JS client, but you can still import the classes you need from `core` and avoid any React dependencies.

```js
import {
    ApolloClient,
    InMemoryCache,
    HttpLink
} from "@apollo/client/core"
// Use cross-fetch for Node versions lower than 18.
import fetch from 'cross-fetch'

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: new HttpLink({ uri, fetch }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    name: "my client",
    version: "1.0.0",
    assumeImmutableResults: true
})

const query = gql`
    query Query {
        hello
    }
`
const response = await client.query({ query })
```

Also note that there used to be a bug with old versions of `@apollo/client/core` having an unnecessary React dependency, I'm using `"@apollo/client": "^3.6.5"` and don't have that issue.