# How to call GraphQL API from Node.js/Express server?

Tags: node.js, express, graphql

I recently implemented a schema and some resolvers for my Express server. I tested them successfully through `/graphql` and now I would like to call the queries I implemented when accessing from a REST API, like so:

```
//[...]
//schema and root correctly implemented and working
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
  schema: schema,
  rootValue: root,
  graphiql: true,
}));

//I start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('We are live on ' + port);
});

//one of many GET handlers
app.get("/mdc/all/:param", function(req, res) {
    //call one of the (parametrized) queries here
    //respond with the JSON result
});
```

How can I call the queries I defined with GraphQL inside my GET handlers? How do I pass parameters to them?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you want to return from that route?

Comment: Right now nothing, I would like to return some JSON containing the result of the query and use AXAJ to retrieve it from the frontend.

Comment: I ended up using the Apollo Client lib for this. Here's how. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72534090/4124574

Answer (score 8):

Basically you can just use http post method to fetch the data from a  GraphQL API, but here very nice solution using node-fetch , to install it:

> npm install node-fetch --save

and the code to use it is:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const accessToken = 'your_access_token_from_github';
const query = `
  query {
    repository(owner:"isaacs", name:"github") {
      issues(states:CLOSED) {
        totalCount
      }
    }
  }`;

fetch('https://api.github.com/graphql', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({query}),
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
  },
}).then(res => res.text())
  .then(body => console.log(body)) // {"data":{"repository":{"issues":{"totalCount":247}}}}
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

this solution was taken from [here](https://blog.apollographql.com/4-simple-ways-to-call-a-graphql-api-a6807bcdb355)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [graphql-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-request).

```js
import { request, GraphQLClient } from 'graphql-request'

// Run GraphQL queries/mutations using a static function
request(endpoint, query, variables).then((data) => console.log(data))

// ... or create a GraphQL client instance to send requests
const client = new GraphQLClient(endpoint, { headers: {} })
client.request(query, variables).then((data) => console.log(data))
```