# How to call a GraphQL query/mutation from an Express server backend?

Tags: express, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

My frontend is `localhost:3000`, and my GraphQL server is `localhost:3333`.

I've used react-apollo to query/mutate in JSX land, but haven't made a query/mutation from Express yet.

I'd like to make the query/mutation here in my `server.js`.

```
server.get('/auth/github/callback', (req, res) => {
  // send GraphQL mutation to add new user
});
```

Below seems like the right direction, but I'm getting `TypeError: ApolloClient is not a constructor`:

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const ApolloClient = require('apollo-boost');
const gql = require('graphql-tag');


// setup
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:3333/graphql'
});
const app = next({dev});
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express();

    server.get('/auth/github/callback', (req, res) => {
      // GraphQL mutation
      client.query({
        query: gql`
          mutation ADD_GITHUB_USER {
            signInUpGithub(
              email: "email@address.com"
              githubAccount: "githubusername"
              githubToken: "89qwrui234nf0"
            ) {
              id
              email
              githubToken
              githubAccount
            }
          }
        `,
      })
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    });

    server.listen(3333, err => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(`Ready on http://localhost:3333`);
    });
  })
  .catch(ex => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

[This post mentions Apollo as the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52832210/how-to-call-graphql-api-from-node-js-express-server), but doesn't give an example.

How do I call a GraphQL mutation from Express server `:3000` to GraphQL `:3333`?

Comment: hi Chance, could you explain a little bit more about your issue? I don't understand... you said you've used `react-apollo` (React side...) but then you don't know how to query from React? I don't understand.

Comment: [Server-side rendering](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/server-side-rendering.html#server-rendering)

Comment: hey, @JVLobo - I updated my question.

Comment: cool, more clear now :)
I've posted an answer, hope it helps

Comment: I wouldn't use a fully-featured client to do server-side requests. You can use something really simple like [graphql-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-request) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more likely to be what you're looking for:

```js
const { createApolloFetch } = require('apollo-fetch');

const fetch = createApolloFetch({
    uri: 'https://1jzxrj179.lp.gql.zone/graphql',
});


// Example # 01
fetch({
    query: '{ posts { title } }',
}).then(res => {
    console.log(res.data);
});


// Example # 02
// You can also easily pass variables for dynamic arguments
fetch({
    query: `
        query PostsForAuthor($id: Int!) {
            author(id: $id) {
                firstName
                posts {
                    title
                    votes
                }
            }
        }
    `,
    variables: { id: 1 },
}).then(res => {
    console.log(res.data);
});
```

Taken from this post, might be helpful to others as well: https://www.apollographql.com/blog/graphql/examples/4-simple-ways-to-call-a-graphql-api/

Comment: For anyone still out there, `apollo-fetch` is [officially deprecated](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-fetch#deprecated) now and will no longer be receiving future updates  So I'd advise against following this answer. This leaves [fetch](https://moonhighway.com/fetching-data-from-a-graphql-api), [axios](https://medium.com/@stubailo/how-to-call-a-graphql-server-with-axios-337a94ad6cf9), or even [graphql-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-request) as possibly the best alternatives out there. Personally, I'm leaning more towards Prisma's `graphql-request`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [graphql-request](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-request), it is a simple GraphQL client.

```
const { request } = require('graphql-request');

request('http://localhost:3333/graphql', `mutation ADD_USER($email: String!, $password: String!) {
  createUser(email: $email, password: $password) {
    id
    email
  }
}`, {email: 'john.doe@mail.com', password: 'Pa$$w0rd'})
.then(data => console.info(data))
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```

It also support CORS.

```
const { GraphQLClient } = require('graphql-request');

const endpoint = 'http://localhost:3333/graphql';
const client = new GraphQLClient(endpoint, {
  credentials: 'include',
  mode: 'cors'
});

client.request(`mutation ADD_USER($email: String!, $password: String!) {
  createUser(email: $email, password: $password) {
    id
    email
  }
}`, {email: 'john.doe@mail.com', password: 'Pa$$w0rd'})
.then(data => console.info(data))
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```

I use it to make E2E tests.

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting *ApolloClient* with `require` instead of `import` I think you are missing this part:

```
// es5 or Node.js
const Boost = require('apollo-boost');
const ApolloClient = Boost.DefaultClient;
```

or

```
const ApolloBoost = require('apollo-boost');
const ApolloClient = ApolloBoost.default;
```

Try one of those and see if it works.

Comment: The 2nd did the trick, but now it's looking for a `fetch`: `Error: 
fetch is not found globally and no fetcher passed, to fix pass a fetch for
your environment like https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch. >>> For example: import fetch from 'node-fetch'; import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';`

Comment: I'm diving into this now... https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/http.html

Comment: How can I require `createHttpLink `?

Comment: I guess something like `const HttpLink = require("apollo-link-http").HttpLink;` or `const { HttpLink } = require('apollo-link-http');` should do it

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add one more way to query from express.
This is what I ended up with.

install required packages

```
npm install graphql graphql-tag isomorphic-fetch
```

write graphql on separate file (myQuery.js)

```
const gql = require('graphql-tag');
const query = gql`
    query($foo: String) {
      // Graphql query
    }
}
```

Main file

```
const { print } = require('graphql/language/printer');
const query = require('./myQuery');
require('isomorphic-fetch');

// other logic

const foo = "bar"
const token = "abcdef"

await fetch('https://example.com/graphql', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ 
      query: `${print(query)}`,
      variables: { foo },
    }),
})
```